# Allow fields to be valid or non-valid based on DateField ranges

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a model called products, see below:

```py
class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    r_price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    d_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default='')
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default='')
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default='')
```

The datefields that I have in my model is called start_date and end_date.

My intention is that if the current date falls within the range of start_date and end_date, d_price will be valid (submitting values within its form).

If the current date is not within the range of start_date and end_date or if the current date surpasses the end date, the r_price field will be valid into taking values to be submitted and d_price will no longer be valid.

See below for views based on the model of when creating and updating instances.

When creating instances -

```py
def NewProductProfile(request):
    form = CreateProductForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateProductForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('product_list')
    return render(request, 'accounts/new_product_profile.html', {'form': form})
```

When updating instances -

```py
def EditProduct(request, pk):

    product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = ProductForm(instance=product)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, instance=product)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('product_list')

    return render(request, 'accounts/edit_product_profile.html', {'form': form})
```

Valid, meaning that the field mentioned will be activated.

For example, if the current date falls in the range of start_date and end_date, when updating the instance when submitting the form.

The Float value with in r_price will not be considered and not saved within the database when it is submitted within its form, rather it will only consider d_price(if the current date falls within the range of the start_date and end_date).

Therefore if the current date is not in between the start_date and end_date, the float value in d_price will not be saved, but r_price will be saved within the database when updating instances of the product when submitting through the form.

The start_date and end_date fields will be manual inputted by the intended user.

How will this be implemented?

Comment: What do you mean with 'd_price/r_price will be valid for taking values'?.

Comment: I have edited the post for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

`Model.clean()`

> This method should be used to provide custom model validation, and to
> modify attributes on your model if desired. For instance, you could
> use it to automatically provide a value for a field, or to do
> validation that requires access to more than a single field.

You should do something along these lines according to your logic.

```
class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    r_price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    d_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default='')
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default='')
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default='')


    def clean(self):
        if self.start_date < datetime.now() < self.end_date:
            self.r_price = None

        elif self.end_date < datetime.now():
            self.d_price = None
```

**Note: Models clean method is not called when model instance is saved so you'll have to manually call it in Models save method.**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, as I am getting error which is "module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'". Is it possible for me to have an another DateTimeField with having a auto_now_add=True.

Comment: @kamcoder you need to add the import like this `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: Yes, but now I'm receiving an error like so, "'<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'datetime.datetime'"

Comment: you would need to handle it accordingly. In the post, you mentioned that end_date and start_date  fields will be manually inputted by the intended user but here they are `None`.

Comment: Yes, I have manually inputted the values for d_price, start_date and end_date to test.